# Increasing book depth

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to create a large book on a Drupal site with at a maximum book depth of 18. Is there a way to increase the current book depth limit of 9 in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to change a value in the menu.inc file:

{drupal7}/includes/menu.inc (line#265 on drupal 7.0):

```
/**
 * The maximum depth of a menu links tree - matches the number of p columns.
 */
define('MENU_MAX_DEPTH', 9);
```

You will have to change the value here to enable to have more nested book, AFAIK.

Comment: That didn't seem to do it, getting this scary error: http://i.imgur.com/OzeLH.png

Comment: I think going back and adding columns to the database may resolve the issue.